# Search for content inside a compressed folder

Tags: c#, c++, directory, unzip, compression

I have a compressed folder (like a zip), and I want to grab one specific file (actually its contents) from it. I don't want to unpack everything and generate lots of files that I would need to delete later, I just want the contents of a specific file in a Stream.

I've tried Quazip, in C++/QT, but it always creates new files, and it didn't work for me as expected. I didn't find anything else on C++ (all other solutions I found, like ZLib, were using single files, and I have a folder with several files).

I've also made some research on C# tools (I thought I could create a class library that would just extract the contents of the desired file for me, so I could use it in my C++ project), but I didn't find how to navigate inside the uncompressed Stream with System.IO.Compression.GZipStream (I'm kind of new on C#) to find the file I want. I found also reference to System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive, but I don't know why my compiler doesn't recognize it (class not found), so I don't know if it would work.

So I'm asking you, how could I do that? Is it possible? It could be in any language, as long as I could generate a lib/dll I could use in my C++ project, and it should work on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried libzip (http://www.nih.at/libzip/libzip.html)? zip_fopen() seem to be able to open a file from a compressed folder.

Comment: I didn't know this libzip. Thanks for the tip, I'll check if it does what I need.

Comment: I`ve downloaded and compiled this lib. It seems it works with large archives However, I still didn't find how to pick an specific file from an archive. Do you know how to use this lib?

Comment: I found out how to pick an specific file from the zip with libzip! I actually used libzippp (which is built over libzip) as a sample to do that (method getEntry) - https://github.com/ctabin/libzippp